# SQLLOGDIR token maps to wrong path

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've some jobs running, which use the `SQLLOGDIR` token. 
Currently it places output in the following location: `D:\sql\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log`

However, I'd like to log it to `H:\`

I've been into the "SQL Server Configuration Manager", where I've changed a startup paramter, `-eH:\ERRORLOG`.

Then, I restarted the entire server, for good measure.

However, the job still thinks `SQLLOGDIR` maps to the path on `D:\` instead of `H:\`.

What else could be needed to change `SQLLOGDIR`?

I'm running MSSQLServer 2016 enterprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that SQLLOGDIR doesn't map to the SQL Server error log folder path, but rather that of the SQL Server Agent!

So the problem was fixed, by rightclickling on the "Error Logs" folder, under SQL Server Agent, in SSMS, and choosing configure. 
[Configure context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Q31.png)

Here i could set the correct path.
[Configure window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U3gz.png)